# How to embed Twitter  and E-mail links inside a webform?

Tags: nodes, webforms, social-network

I want to embed inside a webform a Twitter and E-mail button,so
as the user to post/share the page to his Twitter account or e-mail it.
How to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a module for that, in fact there are many. Since a webform is a node, it makes the possibilities much greater. An example of a module that allows users to share your content in various ways is the [Service links](http://drupal.org/project/service_links) module.